# Do I need a visa to Turkey if I am crossing from Georgia?

Tags: visas, georgia-country, turkey, egyptian-citizens

I am Egyptian. I will travel to Georgia in February. I have the visa for Georgia and I would like to cross from Georgia to Turkey by bus. Do I need a visa? And if so, where should I get it? Egypt or Georgia?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Turkish website about visas, Egyptian tourists do need a visa for Turkey. So far I didn't find details like whether you have to pay, how much, and what duration the visa lasts for.

There is a Turkish embassy in Cairo, so you should apply there for your Turkish visa.

Comment: There is a Turkish embassy in Tsbili. @sarah-maklad would need to apply for a Turkish visa at a Turkish embassy, not an Egyptian one. She could do this in Cairo, but may also be able to do it in Tsbili.

Comment: @imoatama: How right you are! I don't know how I could've made such a silly mistake. I'll strike out the middle paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You need visa to Turkey as per the Consulate website https://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/VisaInfo/Index

> Ordinary passport holders may obtain their 30-day single-entry e-Visas
>   via www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they have a valid Schengen or USA,
>   UK, Ireland visa or residence permit and that they travel to Turkey
>   with Turkish Airlines or Egypt Air.
>
> Besides, those ordinary passport holders who are under 20 or over 45
>   years old may get their 30-day single-entry e-Visas via the website
>   www.evisa.gov.tr.

On the e-visa site for Egyptian passport there is a condition for the e-visa

> - I have a round-trip ticket with Turkish Airlines, Pegasus Airlines,
>     Onur Air or Egypt Air.

However my experience while traveling last month to Sabiha airport with NileAir, e-visa was accepted!

If you want to be on the safe side you can apply for visa at Embassy (Cairo or Alexandria) and you can get the visa in 3 working days. To do that check the visa page https://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/Visa and fill application online and upload all required documents then schedule an appointment.

- Biometric Photo
- Documents attesting to the income status of the applicant and
  inviting person
- Flight Reservation
- Hotel Booking or Invitation
- Supporting document on the applicant's commitment to return (Land
  registry, business certificate, salary table, bank account statement)